# SQL Missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a view using SQL Developer and am encountering a weird error. There seems to be a missing right parenthesis, but I can't find out where - could you help me?

INPUT :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MAST_SOMME_POINTS_CLUBS AS
  (SELECT C.NOM, SUM(R.POINTS) AS POINTS
  FROM MAST_CLUBS C 
    JOIN MAST_NAGEURS N USING(CLUB) 
    JOIN MAST_RESULTATS R USING(NRLIGUE)
  GROUP BY (C.CLUB, C.NOM)
  ORDER BY C.NOM);
```

OUTPUT :

```
Erreur commençant à la ligne: 1 de la commande -
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MAST_SOMME_POINTS_CLUBS AS
  (SELECT C.NOM, SUM(R.POINTS) AS POINTS
  FROM MAST_CLUBS C 
    JOIN MAST_NAGEURS N USING(CLUB) 
    JOIN MAST_RESULTATS R USING(NRLIGUE)
  GROUP BY (C.CLUB, C.NOM)
  ORDER BY C.NOM)
Rapport d'erreur -
Erreur SQL : ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just avoid using unnecessary parentheses:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MAST_SOMME_POINTS_CLUBS AS
   SELECT
      C.NOM,
      SUM(R.POINTS) AS POINTS
   FROM
      MAST_CLUBS C 
   JOIN
      MAST_NAGEURS N
      USING (CLUB) 
   JOIN
      MAST_RESULTATS R
      USING (NRLIGUE)
   GROUP BY
      C.CLUB, -- Is this intentional? It is not in your SELECT
      C.NOM
   ORDER BY NOM;
```

As a tip: keeping your code cleanly laid out and structured well helps to avoid a lot of issues.

Comment: Damn you're right! I mean, speaking of what you wrote in your comment, i first thought i should be there because it is the primary key, but it shouldn't :P I removed it and it solved my problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: @AxelSamyn - That is the benefit of cleanly structuring your code. :-)

Comment: @AxelSamyn - Are you sure C.CLUB shouldn't be there? Without it you will get total points for a member across all clubs (if he or she belongs to more than one) - does that make sense in your business? Otherwise you should have C.CLUB, both in GROUP BY **and** in SELECT - then you will get point totals by member AND club combination (two rows for a member of two different clubs).

Comment: Yes sure! there is only one memeber per club ;) so it is working properly!